# Why can't I read the body from POST request in java?

Tags: java, http, post

**Code**

```
public HttpRequest(BufferedReader from) {
String firstLine = "";

try {
    firstLine = from.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error reading request line: " + e);
}

String[] tmp = firstLine.split(" ");
method = tmp[0];
URI = tmp[1];
version = tmp[2];
System.out.println("URI is: " + URI);

if(method.equals("POST")){
    try {
        String line = from.readLine();
        while (line.length() != 0) {
            headers += line + CRLF;
            if (line.startsWith("Host:")) {
                tmp = line.split(" ");
                if (tmp[1].indexOf(':') > 0) {
                    String[] tmp2 = tmp[1].split(":");
                    host = tmp2[0];
                    port = Integer.parseInt(tmp2[1]);
                } else {
                    host = tmp[1];
                    port = HTTP_PORT;
                }
            }
            line = from.readLine();
        }
        headers += "Connection: close" + CRLF;
        headers += CRLF;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading from socket: " + e);
        return;
    }       
}
else {
    System.out.println("Error: Method not supported");
    return;
}

System.out.println("Host to contact is: " + host + " at port " + port); 
    }
```

**Problem**

I am making a proxy server using Java.

The code above handles an HTTP POST Request. It successfully reads the POST header and prints it in the command prompt but the body is missing.

Can you take look at my code and see the problem? Thanks.

(NOTE: I excluded the GET part because there were no problems with that.)

**Result**

[image: Result]

[image: Result]

Comment: Could you edit above to show the output that you receive

Comment: Done. Please check the result part.

Comment: What about changing (line.length() != 0) to (line = from.readLine()) != null)

Using line.length() != 0 may cause an issue if for some reason there is a blank line in the POST before the body.

Comment: Isn't there always a blank line between the headers and the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you still have things to read on the InputStream. That's why when you shut down the browser, there's nothing else to read so is printed. You have to read exactly the number of bytes that is declared in "Content-Length"

Try something like this:

```
int cL = Integer.valueOf(contentLength);
byte[]  buffer      = new byte[cL];
String  postData    = "";

System.out.println("Reading "+ cL + "bytes");
in.read(buffer, 0, cL);
postData = new String(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
System.out.println(postData);
```

The body request will be in the postData string.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how to write a proxy server. A proxy server only has to do the following:

1. Accept incoming connections. For each connection:
2. Read an HTTP CONNECT request.
3. Connect to the target host specified in the CONNECT request and send an appropriate response to the client.
4. If the connect succeeded, copy *bytes* between the upstream server and the downstream client, in both directions simultaneously.
5. When you read EOS in one direction, shutdown the opposite socket for output.
6. When you have shutdown in both directions, close both sockets.

That's it. There is no parsing of POST requests or anything else required. Not even a Reader.

Comment: I'll take note of that. But in the context of my problem, can you say what is wrong with what I have done in getting the post request body as a string? Thanks.

Comment: @jrmeasures The answer to that is implicit in my answer. What you've done wrong is write a whole lot of unnecessary code to do unnecessary things like get the POST request body as a String, when all you should be doing is copying bytes, and not even caring whether it's GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE, ... or where the headers and the body even are. No need for anybody to debug code you should just throw away.